# Unable to validate input using TextFormField and FlatButton

Tags: android-studio, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I am currently working on a flutter application. I am trying to get the user input using TextFormField and passing it to the next page using the Navigator inside FlatButton. But for some reason, it is not working as I expect it to.

Here is the code:

```
TextFormField(
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[200])),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(8)),
                      borderSide: BorderSide(color: Colors.grey[300])),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: Colors.grey[100],
                  errorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  focusedErrorBorder: InputBorder.none,
                  errorStyle: Theme.of(context).textTheme.caption,
                  hintText: 'Phone Number',
                ),
                keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                controller: _phoneController,
                maxLength: 10,
                validator: (value) {
                  print(value);
                  return isPhoneValid(value)
                      ? 'Continue'
                      : "Input : 98XXXXXXXX";
                },
              ),
              FlatButton(
                child: Text('Enter'),
                textColor: Colors.white,
                disabledColor: Colors.grey,
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                onPressed: (isPhoneValid(_phoneController.text))
                    ? () {
                        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder,(context)=>HomeScreen));
                      }
                    : null,
                color: Colors.blue,
              ),
```

and these are  outside the build function.

```
final _phoneController = TextEditingController();

  bool isPhoneValid(String value) {
    print('Function');
    print(value);
    return value.trim().length == 10;
  }
```

For some reason, the onPressed in the FlatButton is always mapped to null. Kindly guide me in this regard.

Thanks in advance.

PS: The validator inside TextFormField also does not seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear the reason why you're building the `onPressed` in that way, it's not going to work the way you expect. Change your onPressed method to this

```
onPressed: () {
    if (isPhoneValid(_phoneController.text)) {
        Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder,(context)=>HomeScreen));
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

In order to disable button until text field is valid you have to listen for text changes

```
bool _canPressButton = false;

@override
void initState() {
  _phoneController.addListener(_checkIfCanPressButton);

  super.initState();
}

void _checkIfCanPressButton() {
  var canPressButton = isPhoneValid(_phoneController.text);
  if (canPressButton != _canPressButton) {
    setState(() => _canPressButton = canPressButton);
  }
}
```

Then you could do

```
onPressed: _canPressButton ?
    ? () => Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => HomeScreen))
    : null,
```

Comment: Thank you. This works but I want the button to be disabled when the condition is not true.

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you also help me with the validator part.

Comment: @MANOJKUMAR: what is not working? It seems OK for me.

Comment: I am not able to see any validator message.